# Module that adds &nbsp after one letter words

Tags: 7

I'm Polish. In my language leaving one letter words at the end of the line is a mistake. I know i can deal with it adding `&nbsp;` after such words. Is there a module which takes care of it (eg. while saving the content to db)?
RtL

Comment: How are you planning to determine what the end of a line is? That would usually depend on font size, browser viewport size, and other factors which can't be controlled on the server side

Comment: @Clive I would imagine it doesn't matter, adding the non-breaking space at EVERY single character "word" would work without having to know that information.

Comment: @jdu But if the one letter word is _2_ characters from the end of a line, then this method will push it to the _end_ of the line, hence grammatically incorrect, no? I'm not Polish so I might have missed something :)

Comment: @Mołot Same thing I said to jdu...

Comment: @Clive - my mistake, &nbsp; should be after one letter word, not before it. I'm so used to it I didn't notice OP made mistake.

Comment: @Mołot And the world makes sense again :)

Comment: @Clive the fact you're not from our beautiful country actually helped you **not** to miss something ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional Drupal way is to use Text Filters. Here you have [introduction text](https://drupal.org/node/213156) - it's for Drupal 6, but nothing important changed since then. [Examples for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples) contains example filter. Use [regex replace or other method from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094751/php-regex-replace-white-space-by-nbsp-if-it-is-following-single-letter) to make actual replacement:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\b[a-z]) /i', '&nbsp;', $s);
```

All the rest you can copy-paste from Examples.

Comment: @RichardtheLionheart - consider editing your question to correct your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT want to do this when the node is displayed.  String functions are costly, and on this scale it would be an absolute nightmare.

My suggestion is that you make use of `hook_node_submit`

When the node is submitted (aka created or updated) you can run string functions on the body of the node and add your non-breaking space there.

note that this is still going to be a hit to performance, so make sure you're using the appropriate string search functions to make it faster.

Comment: Actually, text filters on display are the Drupal way, and with proper caching and Boost they are next to free.

Comment: Don't let chx see this - he chewed me out once for altering formatted data before it gets to the database. In his words you should _never_ do that. With proper caching using a filter should never be an issue anyway

Comment: Of course improper caching is pretty common... so it's kinda "choose your poison" situation.